# Assistance understanding the output of “netstat -b”

Tags: networking, command-line

I’m using Windows 7 64-Bit, and ran `netstat -b` and it outputted the data to a text file. Their are 4 columns “Proto,” “Local Address,” “Foreign Address,” and “State. The “Foreign Address” states my computer name, and a port number. Their are at least 9 others like this, just a different port on the local address and foreign address.

For example:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    127.0.0.1:2559         Someuser-PC:54735      TIME_WAIT
```

What does this mean? Should I be concerned?

Comment: Without knowing what program is/was listening on or opening the ports it is impossible to say whether you should worry about it. Each row should have the name of the program on the following line ...

Comment: These ones don't. The other ones do, I can see DropBox, FireFox etc... but these address don't have a program associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This answer is meant to be in addition to Giacomo1968's answer.  He's quite right; I'm also answering because I felt that I have some more details to add.  I let that answer speak to the TCP port 2559.

Since you're connection is with 127.0.0.1, this means that a program on your PC is communicating with a program (probably a second program) on your PC.

For active connections, chances are that you have a matching entry.  So, in addition to:

`Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    Someuser-PC:54735      127.0.0.1:2559         ESTABLISHED`

you may also have:

`Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    127.0.0.1:2559         Someuser-PC:54735      ESTABLISHED`

That may be less likely to be true for TIME_WAIT status.  I think I would look for it if I was seeking to gather more info as part of the troubleshooting process.

`Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    Someuser-PC:54735      127.0.0.1:2559         TIME_WAIT`

you may also have:

`Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    127.0.0.1:2559         Someuser-PC:54735      TIME_WAIT`

I would also get rid of the system names.  I typically use `netstat -nab` (in modern MicrosoftWindows versions) because it's faster and more clear.  Without the n after the hyphen, netstat performs a reverse name lookup, which is why 127.0.0.1 looks like Someuser-PC.  It's slower, and less clear, because the actual IP packets do actually use the numeric IP address, not the text names.  (If I want to know 127.0.0.1's name, I can perform a reverse name lookup manually, myself.)  If there was a malicious attacker, I wouldn't want a forward lookup of GoodGuy to point to 192.0.2.10, and then a reverse lookup of 198.51.100.50 to resolve to GoodGuy, and then I manually look up GoodGuy and start incorrectly blaming 192.0.2.10 when the address that is really attacking me is 198.51.100.50.  I avoid that fallacy by sticking with the numbers, which is faster anyway.

You might need to run this as an Administrator to get the best available process name.  (I don't just mean an account in the Administrators group; if you have UAC, you may need an Administrator prompt to get past UAC's restrictions.)

Port 54735 is probably the outgoing connection, since it is in IANA's ephemeral port range.  Basically what that means is that the numbers are reserved/intended for outgoing connections.  (The range is customizable, so I'm basing this comment on defaults.  The term "ephemeral" port is a standard term that can be used to look up more details.)

Generally, for security purposes, TCP connections are of concern if they are ESTABLISHED or LISTENING (because LISTENING can turn into an ESTABLISHED connection).  TIME_WAIT should disappear on its own after a length of time; I wouldn't worry about that unless you have a lot.  (Sometimes web servers will generate a lot of TIME_WAIT connections because they are creating lots of connections and not closing them properly.  Like, dozens or hundreds, I believe.)  Offhand, I believe this status indicates something like a connection that has given up communicating, and is waiting for the remote end to acknowledge that thte connection is closed.  It might be that netstat isn't showing a related program because the program considers the connection to be closed, and has stopped paying attention to the connection.

Regarding your question about whether to be concerned, my answer in a nutshell is: no.  It simply means that part of your computer is talking to another part of your computer.  If a program on 127.0.0.1 is causing problems, then your problem is that a malicious program is installed on your computer.  That might be a cause of concern.  However, the fact that a program is communicating from and to 127.0.0.1 is typically not a cause of concern, because those connections typically do not add any additional security problems.  Such network connections are rather normal behavior.  So your 9 TIME_WAIT connections from/to 127.0.0.1 are a non-concern.

Comment: Probably the best answer I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

First, [`netstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) is a very simple tool. It simply prints information on network connections, routing tables, interface statistics, masquerade connections, and multicast memberships. Basically, just overall network info. So you say this:

> What does this mean? Should I be concerned?

Well literally this is what I am reading:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    127.0.0.1:2559         Someuser-PC:54735      TIME_WAIT
```

Literally, it just means that your local machine on the IP address of `127.0.0.1` using port `2559` is making a TCP connection to a remote machine named `Someuser-PC` on port `54735` and the state is `TIME_WAIT` which basically means the connection is now closed, but the connection is being kept alive on your machine just in case there are any stray/straggler packets waiting/needing that connection.

Now *why* that connection was made at some point? Unclear. The local address port of [`2559`](http://www.adminsub.net/tcp-udp-port-finder/2559) seems to be connected to the [Linux Terminal Server Project (LSTP)](http://www.ltsp.org) which is described as:

> The Linux Terminal Server Project adds thin client support to Linux
>   servers. LTSP is a flexible, cost effective solution that is
>   empowering schools, businesses, and organizations all over the world
>   to easily install and deploy thin clients.

The foreign address port of [`54735`](http://www.adminsub.net/tcp-udp-port-finder/54735) is in the high range of ports typically considered “dynamic” or “private” but basically meaning, “There are no standard applications that reserve/claim this port in a known way, so these ports are used for random/idiosyncratic/application-specific connections.”

I don’t have deep experience with LSTP nor do I know—or understand—the specifics of your setup, but superficially this seems like a valid and legitimate connection. Many protocols use a known port for the client and then a randomized “private” port on the destination server. So this superficially seems like normal behavior to me. Even if there are dozens of entries being shown by `netstat` because honestly on an PC with any OS, running a basically bare `netstat` command like that—without filtering—will just dump piles of entries on the screen; networking traffic can be noisy on a good day and on a clean system.

Now if you are saying that `Someuser-PC` is your local PC and there are connections to it from your localhost loopback on `127.0.0.1`, then this could all be connected to the way some application on your local machine is working. Meaning for all you know you are running some software that does lightweight LSTP terminal emulation and the core code uses TCP packets to communicate to it’s parent “server” application.

But honestly, with the minimal information your question provides, it’s hard to say otherwise whether is this bad or good. My gut tells me you just have some software installed on your PC that is simply—and non-maliciously—using LSTP terminal emulation to do it’s work. Nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: Someuser-PC is actually the name of my computer, I just changed it to Someuser-PC when I posted. So, my computer is making a connection to itself?